# Flickr API, Function Issue

Tags: python, json, function, api

Below is my code, I am having issues with the function "get_flickr_data."I am not receiving a traceback error, the function is just not returning any data. The function should check whether or not the unique identifier for each request exists in your cache data, and if it does, should access the Python object that represents that data from the CACHE_DICTION.If there is no such data in the cache, the function should make a request to the Flickr Photos Search API for photos tagged with your input string. It should modify the string that is returned from the Flickr API so that it is formatted in JSON.The function should add the new dictionary of data to the cache dictionary, associated with the unique identifier key, and should write all the data in the cache dictionary, now with an additional key-value pair, to the cache file. The RETURN VALUE of “get_flickr_data” regardless of whether it got data from the cache or made a new request and saved data to the cache, should be a dictionary representing search data from the Flickr Photos Search API. Any help would be appreciated.

```
CACHE_FNAME = "cached_data.json"
try:
    filex = open(CACHE_FNAME, 'rb')
    saved_cache = pickle.load(filex)
    filex.close()
except:
    CACHE_DICTION = {}

def params_unique_combination(baseurl, params_d, private_keys=["api_key"]):
    alphabetized_keys = sorted(params_d.keys())
    res = []
    for k in alphabetized_keys:
        if k not in private_keys:
            res.append("{}-{}".format(k, params_d[k]))
    return baseurl + "_".join(res)
def get_flickr_data(search_data,photo_number=50):
    baseurl ="https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/"
    params_d={}
    params_d["tags"]= search_data
    params_d["per_page"]=photo_number
    params_d["format"]= "json"
    params_d["method"]= "flickr.photos.search"
    params_d["tag_mode"]= "all"
    params_d["api_key"] = FLICKR_KEY
    unique_indent = params_unique_combination(baseurl,params_d)

    if unique_indent in CACHE_DICTION:
        flickr_info = CACHE_DICTION[unique_indent]
    else:
        resp = requests.get(baseurl,params_d)
        python_flickr = json.loads(resp.text[14:-1])
        CACHE_DICTION[unique_indent] = python_flickr
        f = open(CACHE_FNAME,"w")
        cache_str_tmp = json.dumps(CACHE_DICTION)
        f.write(cache_str_tmp)
        f.close()
    return CACHE_DICTION
get_flickr_data("mountains",50)
```

Below is some of the data from "pset7_cached_data.json"....due to the limit I could not post all of it.

{"https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/format-json_method-flickr.photos.search_per_page-50_tag_mode-all_tags-alps": {"photos": {"total": "1054369", "photo": [{"isfamily": 0, "title": "2017-02-26-Almsee-0293", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3953", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "0a3c9acb9a", "owner": "56354257@N04", "id": "32602919934"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "2016-12-10-Hochkoenig-8013", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3801", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "a679be116e", "owner": "56354257@N04", "id": "32631595083"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "2016-12-10-Hochkoenig-8041", "farm": 3, "ispublic": 1, "server": "2826", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "b8cde01f80", "owner": "56354257@N04", "id": "33405347396"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "Fanes", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3748", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "5010b4ab57", "owner": "140619052@N04", "id": "33289850742"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "Eibsee, Bavaria", "farm": 3, "ispublic": 1, "server": "2831", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "9ccc32ef33", "owner": "60199917@N02", "id": "33317386691"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "Eibsee, Bavaria", "farm": 3, "ispublic": 1, "server": "2842", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "35ea92c879", "owner": "60199917@N02", "id": "32631213063"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "Eibsee, Bavaria", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3867", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "93d9afb2b9", "owner": "60199917@N02", "id": "33317381491"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "Eibsee, Bavaria", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3761", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "bce444e73f", "owner": "60199917@N02", "id": "33289800442"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "DSC03957", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3854", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "ab02c3e662", "owner": "64067043@N08", "id": "33444407725"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "04a2271 02", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3715", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "f9da860c21", "owner": "47391132@N00", "id": "33444011925"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "04a2271 04", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3799", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "02ee9a4c5d", "owner": "47391132@N00", "id": "33444011475"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "04a2271 05", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3778", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "9ff76730e0", "owner": "47391132@N00", "id": "33444011195"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "04a2271 06", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3909", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "f43939ec75", "owner": "47391132@N00", "id": "33060835430"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "04a2271 08", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3698", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "533c038b10", "owner": "47391132@N00", "id": "33060835210"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "04a2271 09", "farm": 3, "ispublic": 1, "server": "2929", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "e05cdf5ec2", "owner": "47391132@N00", "id": "33060835060"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "04a2271 10", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3723", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "ed7f4bf8df", "owner": "47391132@N00", "id": "33060834940"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "04a2271 11", "farm": 3, "ispublic": 1, "server": "2833", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "e47dc82db0", "owner": "47391132@N00", "id": "33060834740"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "04a2271 12", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3746", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "8d88689613", "owner": "47391132@N00", "id": "33060834550"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "04a2271 13", "farm": 4, "ispublic": 1, "server": "3919", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "73759dda01", "owner": "47391132@N00", "id": "33060834350"}, {"isfamily": 0, "title": "04a2271 14", "farm": 1, "ispublic": 1, "server": "673", "isfriend": 0, "secret": "b7877ca2a6", "owner": "47391132@N00", "id": "33288384312"},

Comment: Can you indicate at which line you are getting the error.

Comment: I added more to my description to provide clarity!

Comment: I ran the same program, it is returning data. Try `print get_flickr_data("mountains",50)` instead of `get_flickr_data("mountains",50)` to check that it is printing data.